# Trying to set constraint - new primary key in table, but getting an error: column "amgettuple" does not exist (pgadmin3)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am creating a new table using pgadmin3 and when I click on constraints to add a primary key, I get this error:

[image]

I searched on google but I'm not finding this "amgettuple" issue.  Does anyone know what this means?  I am new to postgres and using pgadmin, just set it up an hour ago.

Postgres version:  9.6

pgadmin version: 1.22.2

linux mint 18

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install pgAdmin 4. pgAdmin III  was supported up to 9,5 version I think.

Comment: That's so stupid, why the hell did Postgres 9.6 bundled with pgAdmin 3?!

Comment: pgAdmin 4 is so bad, no one wants to use it. It is just a crappy hidden web browser application.

Answer (score 3):

I am also using pgAdmin 3 and got that error. I fixed it by using the Query Tool:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD primary key (column_name);
```